# Printing Position 0 in array that has been created through method calls

Tags: java

I am attempting to create a Deck of Cards using two separate classes that will call upon a createCard method and return and append this card to an array in my DeckOfCards class. So far as I am learning arrays seem to be quite the adventure. My current issue as of right now is I am trying to figure out as to why when I request to Print appendex 0 I am receiving the incorrect card position. So If I input 2 NumberOfRanks and 2 NumberOfSuits and attempt to print out position 0 I will receive the second position. If I attempt to print out using 3 & 3 I get the 3rd position.

Sorry for the block of text.

Any thoughts?

```
public class DeckofCards {
    private int NumberOfRanks;
    private int NumberOfSuits;
    private int SizeOfDeck;
    private int whatSuit;

    public void DeckofCards ( int NumberOfRanks, int NumberOfSuits ) {
        this.NumberOfRanks = NumberOfRanks;
        this.NumberOfSuits = NumberOfSuits;

        SizeOfDeck = NumberOfRanks * NumberOfSuits;

        Cards newCard = new Cards();

        newCard.setCards ( NumberOfRanks, NumberOfSuits );

        String[] newDeck = new String [ SizeOfDeck ];
        int counter;
        for ( counter=0; counter <= NumberOfRanks; counter++ ) {

        for ( whatSuit = 1; whatSuit <= NumberOfSuits; whatSuit++ ){
            newCard.createCard ( counter, whatSuit );
            newDeck[counter] = newCard.createCard ( counter, whatSuit );
            System.out.println ( newDeck[ counter ] );
        }

    }
   System.out.println ( newDeck [0] );
}


public String createCard( int newCard, int whatSuit ) {


    createCard = newCard;
    theNumber = Integer.toString(createCard + 1);
    theSuit = Integer.toString ( whatSuit );

    theCard = ( "S" + theSuit + "R" + theNumber );

    return theCard;

}



Output:

How many suits? 2
How many ranks? 2 
S1R1
S2R1
S1R2
S2R2
S1R3
S2R3
S2R1 //Attempt to print position 0

Output:
How many suits? 3
How many ranks? 2
S1R1
S2R1
S3R1
S1R2
S2R2
S3R2
S1R3
S2R3
S3R3
S3R1 //Attempt to print position 0
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure your code is missing a `}` to close the `counter` loop.

Comment: You're generating all the cards of each rank in your inner loop, but each one goes into `newDeck` at the same index.  If you rename the variable `counter` to `whichRank`, it might make the problem clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are not incrementing `counter` every time to add a card, rather you’re incrementing it only once per complete inner loop. By re-using the same index, you’re overwriting values in your array.

Change the outer loop to loop over `rank` and use something like:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int rank = 1; rank <= NumberOfRanks; rank++) {
    for (whatSuit = 1; whatSuit <= NumberOfSuits; whatSuit++) {
        newDeck[counter++] = newCard.createCard(rank, whatSuit);
        System.out.println(newDeck[counter - 1]);
    }
}
```

It’s good practice to minimise the scope of variables, so remove `whatSuit` as an instance field and make it a loop variable, ie `for (int whatSuit; ...)`

Comment: This seems to have worked. Only other thing is if I try to print out the array position every time it goes through the loop it prints out null. But If I specifically ask for a position after the loop has been completed I seem to have no issues getting that position. So in the end that works for me since it is working as intended. I really appreciate you looking over my code and responding!

Comment: The reason I chose to use the counter to do both jobs is because I could not come up with any better way to go about doing this. Other than the fact I posted above it seems to work sort of @KevinAnderson

Comment: The only thing that needs changing in order to actually print out the deck counter each time is the removal of the ++ in newDeck[counter++]. Otherwise it works as intended.

Comment: @Twissted OK, change it to `System.out.println(newDeck[counter - 1]);`, but you should really take the print out of that loop and the printing after loading the cards. Creating and printing are separate concerns

Comment: Yeah I had them in just so I could visualize what was happening within the for loop. Just for the development phase of my coding :) Ty!